# Laptop is having problems with WLAN driver and internet

Tags: windows-10, drivers, internet, internet-connection

My laptop is having trouble with internet connections, it shows that I'm connected with no internet but I'm not even able to ping my router (192.168.0.1)

I have tried the usual ipconfig flush, winsock reset, windows troubleshooting, etc but no luck. I have also reinstalled my drivers both from the laptop OEM and newest one.

When opening Google Chrome ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED is my error.

After typing "ipconfig /all" this is the only output
[ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEth2.png)

I have been trying for hours and I'm dumbfounded, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Try connecting using your smart phone to see if this is a computer / operating system issue or a router issue (wireless setting on router).

Comment: I am using my phone to create this thread, it is not an issue with my router @John

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC on your computer to see if that corrects underlying issues.  ......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John I have completed the steps and it still is not working, I have also tried using Ethernet cable and it also doesn't work.

Comment: You now need to consider a Repair Install on your PC. Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Answer (score 0):

try looking in your Keyboard for Network disconnection, it varies depending on the model, but check.

Usually it goes with the "Fn" key + F3 or F5, but it should be in your keyboard.

Hope it helps!